# DP Adapter to HDMI to Switch to HDMI to Monitor - no signal

Tags: hdmi, displayport

I am connecting my new computer up to an Acer monitor (I have two).

My PC has:

- 3 x `Display Ports`
- 1 x `HDMI Ports`.

The graphics card is `16GB INTEL ARC A770`.

I am testing out a [Switch](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B0815V9HVP) I bought a while back off Amazon - along with 2 x [HDMI 8k Cables](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B0982B1M3J) as well as a [4K DP to HDMI Adapter](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B09P1RYM94).

When connected together I don't get any signal to the monitor.  As per diagram below.

[image: Diagram]

Connecting the `DP to HDMI Adapter` to `Monitor` via a single HDMI works fine.
Connecting the `Computer` to `Switch` to `Monitor` via 2 HDMIs work fine.

It is just the combination of the `DP Adapter` and the `Switch` that does not work - and gives me a no signal on the monitor.  Same issue on both monitors with the issue I have.

Has anyone got a similar setup that works or a recommend setup?  I was wanting to share the monitors with my work laptop so thats why I got the switch.

Comment: Which resolution and refresh rate are you putting of the PC? Because the adapter says it does only 2560x 1600@60Hz.

Answer (score 0):

Your [switch](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B0815V9HVP) is described as:

> Our HDMI SWITCH can support HDMI 1.4 devices perfectly

The 8k cables may be too advanced for your switch because of the
one of the following differences:

- 8k cables have higher speed because of their higher bandwidth of 48Gps, unlike the 4k, which has a bandwidth of 18.2Gps.
  They also use more data than 4k for their frame rate and resolution.
- 8k is an HDMI 2.1 version while 4k is an HDMI 2.0: 8k HDMI 2.1 transmits data at 60 frames per second (fps) and 4k content at 120fps, while 4k HDMI2.0 can only transmit 4k data at 60fps.

Although HDMI is supposedly backwards compatible to all versions,
your switch may still not be compatible with 8K cables, while
your computer and monitor are fully compatible with them.

Reference :
[What Is The Difference Between 4k And 8k HDMI Cable?](https://ventiontech.com/blogs/technology-overview/what-is-the-difference-between-4k-and-8k-hdmi-cable)

Comment: The cables have in their specs "Compatible with all HDMI 1.4 ... devices" (that might be inaccurate... but if we're going based on what it's supposed to be able to do.)

Comment: @YisroelTech: According to the specs everything is supposed to work, but it doesn't... Protocol compatibility may perhaps not be enough to guarantee that two devices can talk together. This seems to me like the right conclusion, based upon the empirical results by the poster.